# Linearization Navier-Stokes

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, navier-stokes

I am considering the classical form of the stationary Navier-Stokes equation given by

$$\frac{1}{Re} (\nabla v,  \nabla \phi) + ((v \cdot \nabla) v, \phi) - (p, \nabla \cdot \phi) = (f,\phi);\qquad (\nabla \cdot v, \xi) = 0.$$

Now, for suitable Reynolds numbers, one can treat the nonlinearity by linearization, e.g. Stokes linearization $(v^{k-1} \cdot \nabla) v^{k-1}$ or Oseen linearization $(v^{k-1} \cdot \nabla) v^k$.

My question: is it also possible to consider  a linearization of the form: $(v^k \cdot \nabla) v^{k-1}$ ?

Comment: I thought the Oseen approximation  substitutes $v=U+\delta v$ and linearizes in $\delta v$ assuming $\nabla U=0$, so $(v\cdot\nabla)v\rightarrow (U\cdot\nabla)\delta v$ without a term $(\delta v\cdot\nabla)U$.

Comment: Of course it is possible, but what would be the point?